# Raspberry PI 3 reading input value with push button

Tags: python, input-device

I am new to Raspberry PI. I am following button tutorial from [adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/playing-sounds-and-using-buttons-with-raspberry-pi/overview) site.

I have the made the connection needed but when I execute the [code](https://learn.adafruit.com/playing-sounds-and-using-buttons-with-raspberry-pi?view=all#code) the following part is not returning values as expected

```
GPIO.input(23)
GPIO.input(24)
GPIO.input(25)
```

it is always returning false resulting in MP3 being played continuously.

I have double checked my circuit and it is as per the diagram shown.

**Update:**

I was able to get it to work by changing the code to setup the pins.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)#added pull_up_down
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)#added pull_up_down
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)#added pull_up_down

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q Dontfail.mp3 &')


    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q Failedme.mp3 &')


    if (GPIO.input(25)== False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q Vadrbrth.mp3 &')

    sleep(0.1)
```

My question now is how come in the video the unedited program was working ? Has something changed in the new version of the Raspberry PI ?

Here is the photo of the circuit

[image: another circuit photo]

The rail at the top is connected with ground and the bottom is connected with 3.3v. The resistor is of 10k Ohm.

**Update 2:**

I did some digging into the code for setup and following were my observations:

If the `pull_up_down` parameter is not passed to the [setup](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/py_gpio.c#l186) function it is assigned as [PUD_OFF](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/c_gpio.h#l49) by default.

When the `pull_up_down`is `PUD_OFF` the process of setting pull up down [function](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/c_gpio.c#l208) executes a different code which I am not able to understand now.

But by passing the value as `PUD_UP` the code necessary for setting it for using pull up resistor is used and it works as intended.

Any explanation regarding what is happening in this [function](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/c_gpio.c#l208) is welcome.

Comment: We are going to need to see all of your code and photos of all the connections in your circuit.

Comment: The sample code is while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q binary-language-moisture-evaporators.mp3 &')
 not what you have above.

Comment: @SteveRobillard : Thanks Steve. Will keep these things in mind while posting any further questions on the site

Comment: We can't answer without seeing your circuit. However, it looks like the circuit is supposed to have pullup resistors.

Comment: How should I put my circuit ? If by using Fritzing then it would be the same as that shown in the image on the site. If not by Fritzing then how ?

Comment: Like I said above PHOTOS! Fritizng shows what you intended to wire up not what you actually wired.

Comment: I have added the photos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51044/discussion-between-anirudha-agashe-and-steve-robillard).

Answer (score 1):

If the other side of the switch is connected to ground, then a "pull_down" function would automatically give you a false result because the pull down resistor is also connecting to ground, effectively giving you a constant button pushed result.  That pin will have a constant LOW (or FALSE) reading.

By applying the pull_up function, you are connecting the pull up resistor to +3.3V and that tells the RPi that the input is HIGH (or TRUE).  This is used to stabilize the input and keep it from floating and possibly giving false readings.

Once you press the button, you effectively short that pin to ground and the RPi gets a LOW reading on that pin.